# Neo4j license in Open Source framework

Tags: licensing, neo4j

I planned to write a small neo4j wrapper in my own framework, which is OS under the Apache 2 license. Is it a problem to publish my code for neo4j under the Apache2 license since neo4j uses the GPL/AGPL license?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can publish the code under Apache License, however the runtime would be under GPL. Got any details?

Comment: Thats the project:
https://github.com/alebon/caladesi-framework/tree/master/caladesi-neo4j